# Tensorflow consecutive slice_input_producer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am confused with how does `tf.train.slice_input_producer` works, I know it returns a dequeue op, but if I apply another `slice_input_producer` on the previous dequeued tensor, it seems the second `slice_input_producer` triggered the first ones dequeue op without finishing slicing.

Here is an example code:

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape([2, 3])
input_x = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.int32)

[row] = tf.train.slice_input_producer([input_x], num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
[cloumn] = tf.train.slice_input_producer([row], num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

print(x)
col = sess.run(cloumn)
print(col)
col = sess.run(cloumn)
print(col)
```

I am expecting 0,1,2,3,4,5 each time I eval `column`. But it gives 0 and 4, the second `slice_input_producer` didn't finishing slicing the first row.

How can I fix this? Many thanks in advance.